# Puede "si" ser el nexo de una oración subordinada sustantiva?

Tags: sintaxis

Estaba intendo analizar: "El problema es si llueve".

Siguiendo un analisis similar a este https://sintaxis.org/oracion-compuesta/subordinadas/sustantivas/atributo/, "el problema" es el atributo y "si llueve" una oración subordinada sustantiva que actúa de sujeto. ¿Es correcto?

"Si" suele ser el nexo de una oración subordinada adverbial condicional, en construcciones "si pasa esto, ocurrirá lo otro". Pero no es el caso de ejemplo inicial. ¿Se puede decir que es una oración subordinada sustantiva y condicional"?

Answer (score 4):

La conjunción "si" puede en efecto introducir proposiciones adverbiales condicionales o proposiciones nominales o sustantivas.

La oración en cuestión:

- El problema es si llueve.

es un caso que puede analizarse de las dos formas, dependiendo de si:

1. La proposición "si llueve" es la condición para que exista el problema (en cuyo caso es condicional). En este caso, si deseamos colocar la condición al inicio, deberemos modificar el artículo: Si llueve es un problema.
2. La proposición "si llueve" define el problema (en cuyo caso es nominal). En este caso, se pueden invertir sujeto y complemento: Si llueve es el problema.

De acuerdo con el contexto y el sentido, podremos definir cuál es el análisis correcto. Lo que es seguro es que la proposición NO puede ser adverbial y sustantiva al mismo tiempo. Intentaré dar un ejemplo de cada caso:

1. No hay ningún inconveniente en hacer el picnic. El problema es si llueve. (Nótese que en este caso también podría decirse: El problema será si llueve, por lo que el sentido es que la eventual lluvia originirá una situación problemática.)
2. (Clase de meteorología)
   A- ¿Cuál es el problema que hay que resolver?
   B- El problema es si (en las condiciones de presión y temperatura dadas) llueve. (En este caso, "problema" es sinónimo de "cuestión": "si llueve" es el problema que hay que resolver. En inglés usaríamos "whether": The problem is whether it will rain (or not).)

Si, de acuerdo con el contexto y el sentido, "problema" puede reemplazarse por "dificultad", la proposición será condicional; si puede reemplazarse por "cuestión", la proposición será sustantiva.

Existe inclusive un caso de una proposición que siempre es nominal pero que puede transmitir el sentido de posibilidad:

- El problema es que llueva.

En modo indicativo, ya no tiene sentido de posibilidad sino de enunciación:

- El problema es que llueve.